# Looking for a very lightweight PHP CMS for single page websites

Tags: php, cms, looking-for-a-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I need a very simple, secure CMS for single-page websites, with a single page backend, multilanguage,  and preferably XML based, although that is not so important... 
I know there are other similar questions, but most of them are quite old.

Please don't suggest Wordpress, it is definitely overkill for something like this.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest ionize.. It's build on codeigniter, easy to create/add modules and has excellent language support :)

http://www.ionizecms.com/

Answer (score 1):

[MediaWiki](http://mediawiki.org/) is pretty popular WIKI, but maybe not as light as you would like? 
Maybe you can find something at [Github](http://github.com/) which fits your needs better by [searching](https://github.com/search?type=Everything&language=PHP&q=cms&repo=&langOverride=&x=24&y=23&start_value=1):

Maybe [gitblog](https://github.com/rsms/gitblog):

> A git-based blog/cms platform for PHP, meant as a replacement for
>   Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

[Perch](http://grabaperch.com/)

I haven't used it (wrote my own instead) but it does seem to be a nice little system for simple CMS needs